# Select latest 10 rows except the first

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What I need to do is (using PHP) select the latest 10 rows from a table except the first (which has the highest ID). How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
ORDER BY `id`  DESC
LIMIT 1,10
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1, 10
```

1 is the offset and 10 is the limit of records it's going to return!

Comment: are you sure? I think first one is the offset to start and the second integer is the LIMIT (numbers of rows) that should be returned, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: No, I am still waiting for your correction, see, I got three downvotes also haha :) don't care just try to learn and go forward

Comment: I did it. But I'm still in shock. Because the was I said was the way I have been using for a long time and it worked for me like a charm :D